# Notification setFullScreenActivity

Tags: android, android-notifications

I have the following code, that's suppose to initialize a new activity during the notification, this is located in a service class

```
Intent push = new Intent();
push.addFlags( Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK );
push.setClass( context, MyActivity.class );
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity( context, 0, push, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT );

long[] vibraPattern = {0, 500, 250, 500 };

Notification noti = new Notification.Builder( getApplicationContext() )
     .setVibrate( vibraPattern )
     .setDefaults( Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND )
     .setFullScreenIntent( pi , true )
     .setContentIntent( pi )
     .getNotification();

notifMng.notify( 0 , noti );
```

The sound and the vibration go nicely, so the noti is successfully notified, however MyActivity is never created, even while it is the FullScreenIntent of this notification.

Answer (score 0):

Notifications are tricky with the API changing so much between different versions. Your solution is targeting API level 11+ (3.0.x) and does not work on any 2.x devices. The getNotification() method is also deprecated in 4.1...

Your notification is missing content to show. It will actually launch the activity when the notification is received but does not display notification because it does not have any content to display.

Add .setFullScreenIntent( pi , true ) if you want to launch an activity immediately upon receiving the push.

I have modified your code so that it works:

```
Intent push = new Intent();
push.setClass(context, MyActivity.class);
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, push, 
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

long[] vibraPattern = { 0, 500, 250, 500 };

Notification noti = new Notification.Builder(getApplicationContext())
            .setVibrate(vibraPattern)
            .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND)
            .setContentIntent(pi)
            .setContentTitle("Title")
            .setContentText("content text")
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .getNotification();

    NotificationManager notificationManager = 
        (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
         notificationManager.notify(0, noti);
```

Comment: Tested the suggested approach: I still get the notification and it's now stored in the notification bar. However, for some reason the Full Screen Intent is not launched...

Comment: If you're testing on a Samsung device, try rebooting it
I came across this problem on the S4 only
FullScreenIntent worked fine on all other devices

Comment: the fullscreen intent will be launch if your phone is locked.

Answer (score 0):

`Notification.Builder` requires API 11+. Use `NotificationCompat.Builder` instead, which is supported only requires API 4+, and allows for the implementation of new features (i.e. new notification styles available in Jelly Bean) on supported devices, while older devices just ignore the new features.  It makes everything much smoother.

See this link for more details: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html

Answer (score -2):

you need following three variables to pass:

1. the color
2. if turning on the led is on
3. if turning off the led is on

if you enable 2 and 3 your led will be blinking, if you disable 2 and 3 the led will be turned off

```
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context );
mBuilder.setLights(Color.RED, 1, 1); // will blink
```